# tababrController Back the first page Issue Iphone

Tags: iphone

Hi
    i Have created tabbarController Application. i have used 5 navigation Controller add within tabbarcontroller.

1. tabButton- home
2. tabbutton- movies
3. tabbutton- songs
4. tabbutton - Dance
5. tabbutton - review

i have select 2 tab- Movies and go their detail page ->list page -> movies detail page
then again click 3 rd tab - Songs
then gain click Movies then show the page Movie detail

I want to show Movie List page.

What will i do?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to reset the state of the movies view controller you can register your app delegate for example as a [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for the [UITabBarController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITabBarController).

When `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` fires you should check to see which tab was selected and send a `popToRootViewController` for the rest of the navigation controllers stored in your tab bar. You have access to the navigation controllers by the `UITabBarController viewControllers` array. You'll need to cast them before calling pop like this:

```
[(UINavigationController *)[[tabBar viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO]
```